# How to send few bits via USB by clicking button at ReactJS web page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usb

I am looking for a solution to send 8 bits via USB with ReactJS website. I would like to do it by onClick button event. Is there something similar to this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-serialport which will work with ReactJS?

Comment: Browsers won't give access to client-local USB ports, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: You actually Can't.

Comment: @Pointy 

So why we can connect with cams or mic via browser?

Comment: @Wrekkler there are well-defined and very specific APIs to expose those resources, including explicit abilities for users to opt out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the browser does not expose this functionality.